# How to seal edges (cracks) in shower?

Tags: bathroom, shower, grout, caulk

Seeing some hairline crack at the edge of the shower. What's the best way to add some waterproofing here? Silicon Caulk? Grout? Something else? Specific product suggestions appreciated.

[image]

Comment: what about mold/mildew

Comment: Are you talking about the crack in the tile at the top of the pic, or the crack between the grout and the aforementioned tile (which should be caulked, as should the vertical corner at the left)?

Comment: @Huesmann - thanks. crack between grout and tile.

Answer (score -1):

From the pic, it looks like you have efflorescence, or deposits from the cement and materials in your shower. This is a sign of water infiltration.

Sealing the cracks is a band aide.  Unfortunately, you should be considering demo of the shower wall and floor. ( The cracks could have been there for some time and the source of the issue.) There may be degradation damage to the support structure.  You need to look deeper into this.